# Help with a "=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(..." formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

Having trouble with a `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(...` formula in grabbing a value from a single cell in another sheet, but only in the row where a particular text value exists in another column in that row.

I am trying this formula:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dMLGkP32EOoHdI6z17zyTwvn2d4MgbOU-vB2nXrE7Dc/edit#gid=1071458711","SCOREBOARD!B49:B58"),"select Col2 WHERE Col1 CONTAINS B1 ")`

with hopes that when I provide my chosen text search value in a cell (`B1`) within the destination sheet, it will then query column 1 of the key sheet and if that text value is found, return the value from Column 2 within the range `B49:B58`.

I am getting an:

> Unable to parse query string for function query parameter 2: NO_COLUMMN:Col2

`#VALUE!` error.

Answer (score 4):

`IMPORTRANGE` requires authorization to access an external spreadsheet, but the authorization pop-up only is shown when `IMPORTRANGE` is not nested inside of other functions.

Once you make the authorization, `IMPORTRANGE` could be nested inside other functions like `QUERY`.

On the other hand, your formula includes a cell reference inside the quotes of the SQL statement. Replace `"select Col2 WHERE Col1 CONTAINS B1 "` by `"select Col2 WHERE Col1 CONTAINS " & B1`

The final formula should look like this:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dMLGkP32EOoHdI6z17zyTwvn2d4MgbOU-vB2nXrE7Dc/edit#gid=1071458711","SCOREBOARD!B49:B58"),"select Col2 WHERE Col1 CONTAINS " & B1)`

Comment: Thanks Ruben....The sheet is authorized. I have just tried this: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dMLGkP32EOoHdI6z17zyTwvn2d4MgbOU-vB2nXrE7Dc/edit#gid=1071458711","SCOREBOARD!A:L"),"select Col2 WHERE Col1 CONTAINS '"B1"')") and it is now properly identifying my search term, but is now returning an #ERROR! Formula parse error

Comment: Does your spreadsheet use a comma or a dot a decimal separator?

Comment: Oh, I see that you formula use B1 inside the SQL statement...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to include more columns in your importrange function.  In other words, you're referencing `Col1` AND `Col2` in your select statement, and yet you are only importing a single column.

For the B1 reference, try `' " & B1 & " '`.