# How to combine 3 sheets into one using QUERY(IMPORTRANGE)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to combine 3 different sheets of data from range `A2:O Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col8, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15` using `Query({IMPORTRANGE(...` function. I tried using the formula below but it's saying

> formula parse error

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ECEMY6zdrIHrtJhvwLm0XnyP4AYOp4YnZ_bp9azLNyM/edit?usp=sharing

```
=QUERY( 
{ 
IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'Termination Review'!A2:O"); 

IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'2nd Week Warning'!A2:O"); 

IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'In Review'!A2:O"); }, 

"Select Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col8, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15 ORDER BY Col1 ASC",1 )
```

Comment: Dumb question but did you allow access ?

Comment: [IMPORTRANGE requires authorization to access an external spreadsheet, but the authorization pop-up only is shown when IMPORTRANGE is not nested inside of other functions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108327/help-with-a-queryimportrange-formula-in-google-sheets) + you have a useless `;` at the end of the third `importrange`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/108329/117311) and the comments alike, you should:
**First authorize the function `IMPORTRANGE` and then use it within the `QUERY`**

Also, since you stack open end columns (`A2:O`) instead of closed end (like `A2:O33`) it is a good idea to constrain the results by using something as simple as `WHERE Col1<>''` in your query.

Summarizing, your query would be:

```
=QUERY( 
{ 
IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'Termination Review'!A2:O"); 
IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'2nd Week Warning'!A2:O"); 
IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'In Review'!A2:O") }, 
"Select Col1, Col2, Col5, Col6, Col8, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15 WHERE Col1 <>'' ORDER BY Col1 ASC",1 )
```

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If not why? If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)